# Javascript RegularExpression is not working

Tags: javascript

If i am giving Special Symbol only at beginning then it's working otherwise it's not working.

For example:

```
var password = '@Sourav12345'

if (password.search(/[@_!#$%^&*()<>?/\|}{~:]/)) {
    return true
 }
else{
  return false
}
```

If i will change password to Sourav@12345.it won't work .Plz. help me

Comment: What is the function supposed to do?

Comment: could you plz tell me whta is the write way to search a string contains special symbol or not

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your regex should work perfectly fine, the issue you are probably encountering is that [`search()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/search) returns the index if the first matched occurencens found, otherwise `-1`.

So only your case where `@` is the first character will evalute to `false` in your condition. You would need to adapt your condition:

```js
var password = 'Sourav12345@.it'
var search = password.search(/[@_!#$%^&*()<>?/\|}{~:]/);
if (search >= 0) {
    console.log(true)
 }
else{
  console.log(false)
}
```

Or use a different mehtod to check against a regex like [`test()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/RegExp/test)

```js
var password = 'Sourav12345@.it'
var test = /[@_!#$%^&*()<>?/\|}{~:]/.test(password);
if (test) {
  console.log(true)
} else {
  console.log(false)
}
```

Answer (score 1):

This is the correct regex:

```
/[@_!#$%^&*()<>?\/\|}{~:]/
```

Just escaped the "/" to make it work

Comment: Another issue is that `password.search` will return an index to the first match. If it's at the beginning it will be 0 which will be false in your if statement. Should be changed to `password.search(/[@_!#$%^&*()<>?/\|}{~:]/) >= 0`.

Comment: Or use `password.test` if you just need true/false

Answer (score 0):

The search() method searches a string for a specified value and returns the position of the match.

if it is not found it will return -1 else it returns the  position number

```js
  var x='@Sourav12345'.search('/[@_!#$%^&*()<>?/\|}{~:]/') > 0?true:false;
console.log(x)
```